# Spring Tool Suite Erro: The project cannot be built until build path

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to start a "Spring starter Project" but after set the application configurations I got the flowing error on the project: "The project cannot be built until build path"

I would appreciate any advise to fix this problem.

Comment: Not enough information there. Are you sure you have the entire error message?

Comment: Hi Paul Hicks, this the full error message: Description Resource Path Location Type
Archive for required library: '/home/jose_carlos/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.13.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar' in project 'project-name' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file project-name  Build path Build Path Problem

Comment: As I said it is about dependency. Download of that file was not completed. Now - delete that directory `/home/jose_carlos/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring‌​-context/4.3.13.RELE‌​ASE` and try to build project again. Maven must download it

Comment: Hi, Vadim thankx for your time...So regarding the problem I have try delete the directory b4, I all so try start a new project in a blank workspace,  but still got the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is about dependencies. Some of required jar files are not available in the build class path.

First steps:

1. Refresh Project
2. Maven->Update Project : it must bring all dependencies into Project Build Path
3. (UPD) Run As... "Maven Install"  :it will give you which dependencies are missed.
4. After all dependencies downloaded into your local Maven repository do "Maven->Update Project" again. Error must be gone after all.

Comment: Hi Vadim, I haven't got the step 3 option "Maven -> build project" any other alternative?

Comment: Sorry, see update - easily Maven invokes from right-click menu: "Run As Maven Install". Personally I prefer to run it as "Maven Build" and set goals as Clean Install, just to make sure to clean target directory and make a build from scratch. When you run it there will be Maven errors if some dependencies are not available. for first time it can take a while Maven downloads needed dependencies. Of course all required repositories like Maven Central must be accessible from your machine. Anyway look at Console messages from Maven. They will tell you what problems are there.

Comment: I still got the same error even flowing your advices. But thankx for all tips